# Use Case in join table with sub query

Tags: mysql, join, subquery, case

I check all question which are related to my questions but I ask it because it is different from that question and I tried but getting error.
Please help me to find solution for this. I already use joins and sub queries but I don't know why in this query I m getting errors. Please check the query and I also added the create query of 2 tables. The query is as below:

```
SELECT * FROM products_features 
CASE WHEN (value_table = 'features_values_float') 
THEN 
    (JOIN features_values_float ON features_values_float.feature_value_id = products_features.feature_value_id) 
WHEN (value_table = 'features_values_int') 
THEN 
    (JOIN features_values_int ON features_values_int.feature_value_id = products_features.feature_value_id)
 END
```

products_features & features_values_float table create statements:

```
CREATE TABLE `products_features` ( `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `qid` varchar(32) NOT NULL, `feature_id` varchar(32) NOT NULL, `value_table` varchar(64) NOT NULL, `feature_value_id` varchar(10) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`), UNIQUE KEY `feature_value_id` (`feature_value_id`), KEY `products_features` (`feature_id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=143854 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `features_values_float` ( `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `feature_value_id` varchar(10) NOT NULL, `value_float` double NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`), KEY `features_values_float` (`feature_value_id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB UTO_INCREMENT=40260 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

[image: The image of errors I m getting by this query]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a [LEFT JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp), A normal join will only join where there is a matching row in the right table. A left join will still show the row but it will just be blank.

```
SELECT
   *
FROM products_features
  LEFT JOIN features_values_float USING (feature_value_id)
```

So you will always see values from both tables, except if there is no information form the right table its values will just be null.

Also a note on joining, if the two column values are the same then you can use `JOIN TABLE_NAME USING (COLUMN_NAME)` which makes it more readable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but Please check my question again that I want to join features_values_float tabel only if the value_table = features_values_float.

Comment: That is what `LEFT JOIN` does, if the value exists in both columns then it will join else it will just show null values.

Comment: Yes but I want records only when it match

Comment: Then just use a normal `JOIN`. It will only return values where the value is present in both tables.

Comment: I already used normal join in case statement but getting error

Comment: You can't use a case statement there. Also `JOIN` alone is enough as that is what it does, it only returns rows where the value exists in both tables